Dynamics 365: Cannot read a record ... An unsupported NULL value has been selected from the Database
Cannot read a record in "CustomTable". An unsupported NULL value has been selected from the database.
This error occurs after adding a new field in one of the principal tables being used in the database in our Acceptance environment and importing the project with these new changes as an XPO to Production.
The error occurs when some users in some servers select a sales order, I understand part of the logic when selecting a sales order the system fetches the record in the table but it cannot be found since it seems to be NULL.
The new field added is a boolean, per definition, it can only be 0 or 1. Somehow, this error only shows when the field is turned to "TRUE." If the field remains "FALSE," this error does not show, because of this somehow I thought it was a cache-related problem but could not find which cache-related files could be causing this issue.
All Production servers are Tier 3.
What I cannot understand is:

The full build has no dependencies or any compilation errors after the import.
Many servers are working just fine and do not present the error when selecting the sales order.
I have run a full build and a DB synchronization and the error persists with the same users.
Why is the error only showing when the field in the table is turned to TRUE for any of the records?

I have tried:

Checking all records with raw SQL scripts to the DB for NULL values. (They are all 0 or 1 when changed).
Deleting the AUC files from the servers and users having these issues.

My experience dealing with Dynamics 365 is that the binary synchronization takes some time to be fully synched in all servers, so I also waited 1 full day to be sure all servers were in synch but, the error persists if the field is turned to TRUE in any of the records in the "CustomTable"
What am I expecting:

Zero null errors when setting to TRUE any of the records in the table.

